# Is it fine to have links to a tutorial website in an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, external-links

I have been contributing to Stack Overflow actively. I have observed that in most of the answers, there are external links to documentation or any other similar questions asked previously.

I tried to look in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and read *[How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)*, but I still have a few questions.

Is it fine to reference a tutorial website or something? If so, what is the best way to do that?

Comment: Make sure to link to credible tutorials... Some links could get you downvotes. Documentation/specification links are unlikely to cause any concerns.

Comment: This is nit a tutorial site, so the title of your question makes no sense.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's fine to do this, but there are some things you should keep in mind how you do it.

Any time you're quoting an outside reference, it's *ideal* to provide a link to it as well as pull in the relevant key nugget of wisdom from your source.

As a reference, you can observe either [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34554460/1079354) that I've recently posted, or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27598164/1079354) which seems to still be getting a lot of attention.  In both answers, I cite my source and offer a summary result of the information in case the resource disappears or goes dark overnight.

If your answer is *just* the link, that's significantly less ideal.  Merely posting a link to the documentation is pretty poor form, and should be avoided since it's likely to get the answer deleted as being link-only.

Also, if the link is an answer that's already here on Stack Overflow, that's a strong signal that the question is a duplicate, and should instead be closed as such.

Finally, if the link is there only to generate clicks, like being to a blog or to some sort of advertisement, and is not related to the answer at all, that is considered to be spam, and is subject for removal as well.

To summarize:  It's fine to post external links in answers, but if you do, use it as a reference and pull context *into* the answer.

Comment: "Jaywalking is pretty poor form, since you're likely to be noticed by an authority and issued a fine"

Comment: _Also, if the link is an answer that's already here on Stack Overflow, that's a strong signal that the question is a duplicate, and should instead be closed as such._  I would agree that's possible, but also agree that some approaches that teach key techniques and concepts are often not direct duplicates to the degree marking them as duplicate would be so strongly suggested. Though, I admit, that may be due to my perception in less common tags. I suspect HTML and JavaScript see huge numbers of duplicates.

Comment: @JanDvorak: It's totally legally here, so... >)

Comment: I would just add the reasoning that being Stackoverflow, we work on a premise that we're always going to be online. If you answer a question without expressing what the link says, your answer will lose all it's value if the link ever dies/gets broken. By pulling data from the source into Stackoverflow, you're perpetuating the knowledge within our community.